# Implement Google Maps Styling Wizard JSON

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, styling

I customized google map's appearance with [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com). It told me to copy the JSON, which I did, but I have no idea where to implement it in my **iOS Swift project**.

Does anyone know where to put it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this piece of code in order to create stylish maps where you have created the `GoogleMaps` object `mapView`

> **Swift 3.x code**

```
do {
        // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file. Make sure style.json is present in your project
        if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
            mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
        } else {
            print("Unable to find style.json")
        }
    } catch {
        print("The style definition could not be loaded: \(error)")
    }
```

The link you posted as Styling Wizard will be used to create a `json` file. Modify your map and create a json. Then copy the `json` and create a new plain text file and paste the json. Give the file name **style.json**. Copy the .json file in your project and use the above code to change the style of your map. Check this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling) for more details.

See the output of my result. I created a silver map.

[image]

Comment: This is AWESOME! Thank you so much!

Comment: Since you've apparently implemented it successfully, could you check out [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064779/google-maps-gmsmapview-on-custom-uiview) on google maps?