# Google Maps GMSMapView on custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview

I want to display google maps on a view that's then added to `self.view`, rather than drawing the map directly on `self.view`. Therefore, I created a view in storyboard and changed its class to `GMSMapView`. I also created an outlet connection to that view called `gmView`.

I am using the following code that does unfortunately not show the map:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))
gmView = mapView
```

Also, I tried adding the `mapView` to `self.view` as a subview, like this:

```
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

...and inserting it:

```
self.view.insertSubview(mapView, at: 0)
```

Note that I'm using Auto Layout if that changes anything.

None of these approaches seem to work for me.
Any ideas?

Comment: if you have already created an outlet, whats the need of allocation the mapView again. Do the things in your same `gmView`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to add a `mapView` after the loading of the `view`, then you need to create an object of `GMSMapView`. So break the outlets of your `mapView` since it will be created dynamically.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    //Take a Google Map Object. Don't make outlet from Storyboard, Break the outlet of GMSMapView if you made an outlet
    var mapView:GMSMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))

        //so the mapView is of width 200, height 200 and its center is same as center of the self.view
        mapView?.center = self.view.center

        self.view.addSubview(mapView!)

    }
}
```

Here is the output. `mapView` is of width = 200 and height = 200 with center as same as `self.view`

[image]

Answer (score 27):

I finally figured out how to display the map in a UIView created in Storyboard and center it in a specific location.

Note: After created the UIView outlet, I changed its class to GMSMapView as explained before.

```swift
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 52.520736, longitude: 13.409423, zoom: 12)
        self.mapView.camera = camera

        let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.520736, 13.409423)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: initialLocation)
        marker.title = "Berlin"
        marker.map = mapView

    }
```

And this is the output: 
[Map centred in Berlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV2Er.png)

Comment: self.mapView.camera = camera  // this is important line

Answer (score 8):

Very Simple. Use Following Steps

1) Open Storyboard: Drop a UIView from Object library in your ViewController.

2) Make custom view outlet in your class. (viewForGMap in my code)

3) Add following line for code in your class.

```
class GMapVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewForGMap: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 28.7041, longitude: 77.1025, zoom: 10.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.viewForGMap.frame, camera: camera)
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.7041, longitude: 77.1025)
    marker.title = "Delhi"
    marker.snippet = "India’s capital"
    marker.map = mapView

   }
```

[image]

OutPut:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can position a blank UIView in your layout, and set its class in the inspector as a GMSMapView. You won't need to programmatically instantiate it.

Then just get a reference via outlet to the view and set your coordinates/camera.

Comment: This!!! This also fixes a lot of problems with autolayout and iPhone Plus!

Comment: Thanks. This basically works for anything that extends the UIView class so it's the def the easiest way to use storyboard and auto layout with custom views

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple way to get a Google Maps hooked up to a `View` in your `ViewController` in a storyboard (Swift 4.2, Xcode 10).

I'm calling my `ViewController` `MapLocationsViewController`.

1. So, in your storyboard, make sure the class on your `ViewController` is properly referencing your correct class (`MapLocationsViewController` for me in this example).
   [image: Step 1]
2. Next, drag a `View` object onto that ViewController and set that class to `GMSMapView`.
   [image: Step 2]
3. Hook that `View` object up to an @IBOutlet in your code (which I named `viewForGoogleMap` in my example).
   [image: Step 3]

Here's a minimalistic example code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
class MapLocationsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForGoogleMap: GMSMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        viewForGoogleMap.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

For further info, check out the [Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#camera_position).

Answer (score 1):

CGRect.zero will return a view with zero height and zero width. It will be invisible.

Also, it doesn't really make sense to add it in to the storyboard if you want to do your own allocation. You should instead just create a property of the view controller programmatically, and set its frame to be whatever you want.

Note, when you call 'addSubview' to a view, it will always be added to the top of the view, so there's no need to insert it at a given index. Using auto-layout is good, but viewDidLoad() gets called before all of the constraints are set. If you want to be able to set your mapView's frame = self.view, you would want to do that in viewDidAppear() instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can use zPosition in iOS.

If we have a view named salonDetailView, eg:

```
@IBOutlet weak var salonDetailView: UIView!
```

[in my case see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pftiZ.png)

and have UIView for GMSMapView, eg:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapViewUI: GMSMapView!
```

To show salonDetailView upper of the mapViewUI use zPosition as below:

```
salonDetailView.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Those answers didn't work for me as I wanted. As an improvement for @Rajan's answer, I thought of adding an **UIView** to storyboard **View Controller** with desired constraints. Then I added another **UIView** inside that as child and then I changed class name to **GMSMapView**. After that I made an Outlet to **UIViewController**.

```
@IBOutlet weak var GMSMap: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: GMSMap.frame, camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 6.9271, longitude: 79.8612, zoom: 10))
    let marker = GMSMarker()

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 6.9271, longitude: 79.8612)
    marker.title = "Colombo"
    marker.snippet = "Sri Lanka"
    marker.map = mapView
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)

}
```