# displaying google map within a UIView

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am using google maps with iOS.

this is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.mapType =  .terrain
    self.view = mapView
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
    marker.title = "my location"
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

How would i get the map to be attached to myMapView UIView?
Is there a way for the marker title to appear always?

thanks

Comment: Can't understand what you wanna do...

Comment: 2 question. get the marker on the map to appear always and not just on click. Another question. I have a UIView named myMapView. The view is a class of GMSMapView. I want The map to appear inside the UIView and not straight in the view of the UIView Controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870455/10505343 is the way I solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the outlet you created.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 17.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.mapType =  .terrain

        // CHANGE THIS
        self.myMapView = mapView

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
        marker.title = "my location"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

Comment: No...., If you check the code, "self.myMapView = mapView" effectively makes both myMapView and mapView be the same instance, therefore anything you do to either will be applied on the other as well. (Because it's actually the same). The issue with OP's code was that he was assigning it to the ViewController's view instead of the actual GMSMapView.

Answer (score 2):

To place a google map inside a UIView, then you need to drag a UIView object onto your canvas and subclass it as GMSMapView then create an outlet to it in your code - then you can use the following code to initialise it:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var miniview: GMSMapView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368, zoom: 6.0)
        miniview.camera = camera
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +31.75097946, longitude: +35.23694368)
        marker.title = "my location"
        marker.map = miniview
    }
```